# Count of weekdays and the time duration per day

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I have a column that has 34 records of Week Day, Month/Day, and Times. I am looking for two formulas that I can use in a table that will give me the count of weekdays and the time duration per day. Eventually, I would like to just copy and past new dates into column A and have the table automatically calculate. Here is my google sheet example. Is there a way to do this without creating helper columns? If not, no big deal. Anything to help automate the process will be helpful.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C6N94QJyEgm-2yg2SEDOweIU2fk2h2DLydKb-nH-ObE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

There are likely to be several ways to answer your question. Please consider this as one approach.

You asked "Is there a way to do this without creating helper columns?"... Yes, though this provides an example of "no helper" and "helper".

**NO HELPER**

**Count of Days**

- Insert this formula in Cell D3:

  - `=iferror(query($A$2:$A$35,"select count(A) where dayOfWeek(A) contains '"& IFERROR(vlookup(C3,{{"Sunday";"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday"},{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}},2,0)) &"' label count(A) ''"),0)`
  - manually copy down to Cell D9

**Time duration per day:**

- Insert this formula in Cell E3:

  - `=iferror(query($A$2:$A$35,"select max(A) where dayOfWeek(A) contains '"& IFERROR(vlookup(C3,{{"Sunday";"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday"},{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}},2,0))  &"' label max(A) ''")-query($A$2:$A$35,"select min(A) where dayOfWeek(A) contains '"&IFERROR(vlookup(C3,{{"Sunday";"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday"},{1;2;3;4;5;6;7}},2,0))&"' label min(A) ''"),0)`
  - format as `Duration`
  - manually copy down to Cell E9

**Totals:**

- Cells D10 and E10 are simple `SUM` formula
- format Cell E10 as `Duration`

---

[image: Snapshot No Helper]

---

**HELPER COLUMN**

- Insert a new column to the left of Column D (Count of Days)

  - Header =  `Day of week`
  - Values: Sunday = `1`, Monday = `2` and so on.
  - This column can be hidden

**Day of the week:**

- Insert this formula in Cell E3:

  - `=iferror(query($A$2:$A$35,"select count(A) where dayOfWeek(A)contains '"& D3 &"' label count(A) ''"),0)`
  - manually copy down to Cell E9

**Time duration per day:**

- Insert this formula in Cell F3:

  - `=iferror(query($A$2:$A$35,"select max(A) where dayOfWeek(A) contains '"&D3&"' label max(A) ''")-query($A$2:$A$35,"select min(A) where dayOfWeek(A) contains '"&D3&"' label min(A) ''"),0)`
  - format as `Duration`
  - manually copy down to Cell F9

**Totals:**

- Cells E10 and F10 are simple `SUM` formula
- format Cell E10 as `Duration`

---

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: The question is "Is there a way to do this without creating helper columns?" but this answer use helper cells. Does it means that it's not possible? :)

Comment: @Rubén "Does it means that it's not possible?" No - you shamed me into revisiting and revising the answer ;). But I'm willing to bet that there's a much more elegant solution than my revision.